# Dynamic data for test with model_bakery

Tags: python, django

How to orginize dynamic data for a test using model_bakery?

```
route_application_requester = Recipe(
    ApplicationRequester,
    form_applicant=cycle(FormChoices.values),
    inn=gen_inn,
)
```

I need gen_inn to get the value from form_applicant, which can be entity or entrepreneur, and generate 10 or 12 digits depending on it.

Answer (score 0):

I understood a little but I`ll try.

- Define a Custom Generator Function: This function should take no arguments but internally it will create an instance with a temporary `form_applicant` to determine the correct inn value.
- Use the `Generator Function` in the `Recipe`: The function will be called when the recipe is baked, allowing it to generate the correct inn based on `form_applicant`.

```py
from model_bakery.recipe import Recipe, seq
from model_bakery.random_gen import gen_integer

def gen_inn():
    """Generate an INN number based on a temporary ApplicationRequester instance."""
    # Create a temporary instance to access form_applicant
    temp_instance = route_application_requester.make(_quantity=1)
    form_applicant = temp_instance.form_applicant

    if form_applicant == 'entity':
        # Generate a 10-digit INN for entities
        return str(gen_integer(min_value=1000000000, max_value=9999999999))
    elif form_applicant == 'entrepreneur':
        # Generate a 12-digit INN for entrepreneurs
        return str(gen_integer(min_value=100000000000, max_value=999999999999))
    else:
        # Handle other cases or throw an error
        return None

route_application_requester = Recipe(
    ApplicationRequester,
    form_applicant=seq(*FormChoices.values),
    inn=gen_inn
)

# Example usage
application_requester_instance = route_application_requester.make()
```

In this updated approach, `gen_inn` function creates a temporary instance of `ApplicationRequester` to access the `form_applicant` value. This is a bit of a workaround, but it allows you to dynamically generate the inn value based on the `form_applicant`.

Comment: It is Recipe object, dont have attribute form_applicant

Comment: Ah, you're right. When using model_bakery's Recipe, the attributes are not directly accessible in the way I initially described. Tried to fix, check now pls.